# Graphlab vs Mahout

Tags: bigdata, classification, python, recommender-system, java

I have some question regarding to the choice of the better implementation. I would know the differences and advantages of [Mahout Apache](https://mahout.apache.org/) (Java implementation) versus [Graphlab](http://graphlab.com/index.html) (Python implementation) in the area of the data sciences. Specially in the area of recommenders and classifiers. Can anybody here get some (qualified) feedback about both possibilities?

Comment: This question is potentially opinion-based, but I think it's specific enough to be valid. I'd like to see if a moderator has any thoughts on this. This exchange is still young, so we are still setting the standards.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of mahout is that it is scalable, apache license , good community and documentation support. Also Fast-prototyping and evaluation
to evaluate a different configuration of the same algorithm we just need to update a parameter and run again.

Comment: Mahout is slow, and didn't make a lot of progress recently. It's dead, IMHO.

Comment: AFAIK it is not dead, they are creating bindings to Spark (cf MLLib) https://mahout.apache.org/users/recommender/intro-cooccurrence-spark.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about MLlib (the hot kid on the block), cloudera-ml, cloudera oryx, cloudera oryx2, and a myriad of other efforts to make old algorithms like k-means solve nonexistant problems on wannabe big data...

## There is no one size fits all.

Thus, there is no answer to your question, in particular no concise answer.